# What is use of .replaceAll("\\s+$","");

Tags: java, split, replaceall

Please anyone tell me what is the difference between:

1. `.replaceAll("\\s","");`
2. `.replaceAll("\\s+","");`
3. and `.replaceAll("\\s+$","");`

Comment: You might also read trough http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html specifically

Answer (score 3):

`s.replaceAll("\\s", "")` Replace each space character with nothing.

`s.replaceAll("\\s+", "")` Replace each group of 1 or more spaces with nothing.

`s.replaceAll("\\s+$", "")` Replace each group of 1 or more spaces at the end of the string with nothing.

All of these special characters are explained well in the javadoc.